# Controller for linked models in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I need to create action in controller to add data from form into database (Entity Framework Core). I have two linked models named **user** and **newsletter.** Ex: When new user is added I need to add him also into newsletter table. I am following this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/complex-data-model?view=aspnetcore-3.1

**There is a code:**

```
    public class user
    {
      [Key]
      public int id { get; set; }

      //Other properties

      public string mail { get; set; }

   
      public virtual newsletter news { get; set; }

    }

   public class newsletter
   {
       [Key]
       public int newsId { get; set; }

       [ForeignKey("user")]
       public int userId { get; set; }

       [Required]
       public bool registered { get; set; }

   }
```

I tried create some action (code below), but when I check details of user, property newsletter is always *null*.

**Controller code:**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> register(user user, bool reg)
    {
        try
        {
            if(ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                user.news = new newsletter() { userId = user.id, registered = reg };
                user.passChng = DateTime.Today;
                _c.user.Add(user);

                await _c.SaveChangesAsync();
            }

            return RedirectToAction("registerForm");

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Content(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

**Result JSON:**

```
{
    "id": 2,

    //Other properties

    "mail": "me@mail.com",
    "news": null,
  }
```

Please can anyone write action to add data into newsletter table and connect it with user? I absolutely haven't got any other idea. Thanx <3.

Comment: Hi Martin, what is your requirement? when sending a user model it should create the user and the newsletter? i can't follow

Comment: When new user is send I need register him also to newsletter table. I following this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/complex-data-model?view=aspnetcore-3.1.

Comment: If there is a 1 .. 1 relationship between User and Newsletter, you should add a navigration property of type ```User``` in your model ```newsletter.cs```. Try with that and let me know. You can always inspect the actual SQL code that entity framework sent to your database with ```SQL Profiler```

Comment: Yes there is 1..1 relationship, but honestly I don't know what do you think "navigation property." I am trying do this first time, so can you edit my code and post it like response please?

Comment: If you mean foreignkey, I have annotation tag [foreignkey("user")] in newsletter class.

Comment: I meant this => https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-one-relationship-in-code-first.aspx. Im not 100% sure that with the data annotation [ForeignKey] is enough to instruct entity framework to create a 1 - 1 relationship between users and newsletters. Add a ```public User User {get; set;}``` (navigation property) to the newsletter class, a ```add-migration {something}``` and a ```update-database``` to update the SQL database. Check if you have follow all the steps in that article

Comment: It not work but I solved it. I don't know that I need .Include() method in my get action. This is correct code: ' var r  =  _c.user.Include(n => n.news).SingleAsync(u => u.id.Equals(id))'

Comment: @RodRamírez but thanx a lot for your time

Comment: Glad to hear that @Martin, keep on working!